# Get the Date of the row with the min value

Tags: python, pandas

edit:
Hello to all,
I have gathered some data from the DAX (stock market). Now I want to return the date where the closing value is the lowest.

The DataFrame looks like this:

[image]

In this case, it should return the date 2009-12-16

I was already trying it with some easy code:

```
for i in dax['Closing']:
    if i==dax['Closing'].min():
```

But after that, I wasn´t able to return the Date of the row.
I tried it with .iloc and some other things. But nothing worked.

I also was trying it with df.idxmin() but it doesn´t help me a lot.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can try `df.loc[df['Closing'].idxmin(), 'Date']`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(dax[dax.Closing == dax.Closing.min()])
```

Now you find the minimum of the 'Closing' column and print the whole row.

Hope that this helps!